# Extern and usage with examples

Tags: c++, extern

Alright, this question is really meant to provide usage of extern with examples in c++.

Comment: i don't want to be rude here  but you said `c++ is a lot like Javascript` : They are worlds apart , there is almost nothing besides `{` and `}` that those 2 have in common.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare a global variable in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702053/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-c)

Comment: When I say "a lot by javascript" I mean the stuff I learned thus far (i.e. for loop, while, do, arraies, switch, etc) though I admit they are different they are more similar than just { }. As for the duplicate, it is not. I looked over the other and it did not seem to be similar though the are, to some extent, talking about similar concepts. I will also add that the purpose of this post is to give newbies an understand of how and why to use this.

Comment: I think your question's title is very misleading. What about changing it to **How to teach the usage of extern for C++?**

Comment: Really people? Here I am trying to provide people the information on how to use extern with examples in c++ who don't know. You all (many) are far to ready to condemn a post before actually reading its content.

Comment: I think your question isn't a question. It's no problem to answer your own question, but if there is no real question, then this will be hard. I suggest to change the title again to something like **How to teach the usage of extern to C++ newcomers by examples** and **tell your story**. **Then** let's see if you or something else can give a goos answer. Give it another try, i'll keep my fingers crossed :)

Answer (score 1):

In C, and thus in C++ too, the programmer should understand that "declaring" a variable is also **defining** its address (not its value!). That's why they need to know the [`extern` keyword in C](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/), which is basically the same as in C++.

Comment: @ReubenRenquist Ok, maybe it's not so great for C++ newbies. But the usage of `extern` for variable declarations in C++ isn't different from that in C.