# C++/DX11 Moving from .h to .cpp causes error

Tags: c++, undefined, header-files, directx-11

I'm working on some `directX`, started from tutorial code and have gradually been converting it into their own class systems and cpp files etc.

Everything has been going well until now, but I just started modifying the "Camera.h" and "Camera.cpp". I've got the class function In the header, and when I place it in its class file it comes up with an error. I've got header blockers and so on but I cant see the flaw.

**camera.h** before editing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evxof.png

**camera.h** after editing

```
#ifndef CAMERA_H_
#define CAMERA_H_
#include "Player.h"
#include "RandomVariables.h"


class Camera {
    public:
        void    UpdateCamera();
        float   camPitch;
        float   camYaw;
        float   Zoom_Amount; //zoom amount from Model_1.Player
        float   charCamDist; //distance from Model_1.Player

        XMVECTOR camPosition;
        XMVECTOR camTarget;
        XMVECTOR camUp;
        XMVECTOR camRight;
        XMVECTOR camForward;

        XMMATRIX camRotationMatrix;
        XMMATRIX Rotationx;
        XMMATRIX Rotationy;
        XMMATRIX Rotationz;
        XMMATRIX camView;
        XMMATRIX camProjection;
};

Camera MainCamera;

#endif
```

I remove void Camera::UpdateCamera() and put it in the camera.cpp and it comes up with undefined errors and so on which don't happen if void Camera::UpdateCamera() is in the header file so I'm baffled :S

**error list**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G21V.png

**Camera.cpp** after moving updatecamera

```
#include "Camera.h"

void Camera::UpdateCamera(){
    MainCamera.charCamDist = 135.0f;

    MainCamera.camTarget = mainPlayer.playerPos;

    MainCamera.camTarget = XMVectorSetY(MainCamera.camTarget, XMVectorGetY(MainCamera.camTarget)+5.0f); 
    MainCamera.camTarget = XMVectorSetX(MainCamera.camTarget, XMVectorGetX(MainCamera.camTarget) -MainCamera.Zoom_Amount);


    MainCamera.camRotationMatrix = XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(-MainCamera.camPitch, MainCamera.camYaw, 0);
    MainCamera.camPosition = XMVector3TransformNormal(DefaultForward, MainCamera.camRotationMatrix );
    MainCamera.camPosition = XMVector3Normalize(MainCamera.camPosition);

    MainCamera.camPosition = (MainCamera.camPosition * MainCamera.charCamDist) + MainCamera.camTarget;

    MainCamera.camForward = XMVector3Normalize(MainCamera.camTarget - MainCamera.camPosition);  // Get forward vector based on target
    MainCamera.camForward = XMVectorSetY(MainCamera.camForward, 0.0f);  // set forwards y component to 0 so it lays only on
    // the xz plane
    MainCamera.camForward = XMVector3Normalize(MainCamera.camForward);
    MainCamera.camRight = XMVectorSet(-XMVectorGetZ(MainCamera.camForward), 0.0f, XMVectorGetX(MainCamera.camForward), 0.0f);

    MainCamera.camUp =XMVector3Normalize(XMVector3Cross(XMVector3Normalize(MainCamera.camPosition - MainCamera.camTarget), MainCamera.camRight));

    MainCamera.camView = XMMatrixLookAtLH( MainCamera.camPosition, MainCamera.camTarget, MainCamera.camUp );


};
```

**RandomVariables.cpp**

```
//Global Declarations - Interfaces//

#ifndef RAND_H
#define RAND_H
#include "Models.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Camera.h"

///start
My_Player   mainPlayer;

XMMATRIX WVP;

XMVECTOR DefaultForward = XMVectorSet(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f);
XMVECTOR DefaultRight = XMVectorSet(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);

float tilt_X = 0.0f;

int NumSphereVertices;
int NumSphereFaces;

XMMATRIX sphereWorld;


XMMATRIX Scale;
XMMATRIX Translation;

///end



IDXGISwapChain* SwapChain;
ID3D11Device* d3d11Device;
ID3D11DeviceContext* d3d11DevCon;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* renderTargetView;
ID3D11DepthStencilView* depthStencilView;
ID3D11Texture2D* depthStencilBuffer;
ID3D11VertexShader* VS;
ID3D11PixelShader* PS;
ID3D11PixelShader* D2D_PS;
ID3D10Blob* D2D_PS_Buffer;
ID3D10Blob* VS_Buffer;
ID3D10Blob* PS_Buffer;
ID3D11InputLayout* vertLayout;
ID3D11Buffer* cbPerObjectBuffer;
ID3D11BlendState* d2dTransparency;
ID3D11RasterizerState* CCWcullMode;
ID3D11RasterizerState* CWcullMode;
ID3D11SamplerState* CubesTexSamplerState;
ID3D11Buffer* cbPerFrameBuffer;

ID3D10Device1 *d3d101Device;    
IDXGIKeyedMutex *keyedMutex11;
IDXGIKeyedMutex *keyedMutex10;  
ID2D1RenderTarget *D2DRenderTarget; 
ID2D1SolidColorBrush *Brush;
ID3D11Texture2D *BackBuffer11;
ID3D11Texture2D *sharedTex11;   
ID3D11Buffer *d2dVertBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer *d2dIndexBuffer;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView *d2dTexture;
IDWriteFactory *DWriteFactory;
IDWriteTextFormat *TextFormat;

IDirectInputDevice8* DIKeyboard;
IDirectInputDevice8* DIMouse;

ID3D11Buffer* sphereIndexBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer* sphereVertBuffer;

ID3D11VertexShader* SKYMAP_VS;
ID3D11PixelShader* SKYMAP_PS;
ID3D10Blob* SKYMAP_VS_Buffer;
ID3D10Blob* SKYMAP_PS_Buffer;

ID3D11ShaderResourceView* smrv;

ID3D11DepthStencilState* DSLessEqual;
ID3D11RasterizerState* RSCullNone;

ID3D11BlendState* Transparency;

#endif
```

Comment: `Camera MainCamera;`  Putting this in the header makes you susceptible to the "multiple definition" linker error.  If you include `camera.h` in multiple source files, there will be multiple `MainCamera`'s declared, which will lead to such an error.  As a matter of fact, that is what *will* happen, even if you address the compilation issues.

Comment: given its got #ifndef it shouldnt be able to redefine the MainCamera? it is included in multiple files prior to moving the cameraupdate function

Comment: No.  That is not what will happen.  You have 2 separate modules, RandomVariables.cpp and Camera.cpp.  They will be compiled separately, no?  So when the linker now sees that the `MainCamera` variable appears in both the RandomVariables and Camera object code, the linker will emit the error.  Either stop using global variables, or learn how to use them in a multi-module program.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702053/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-c

Comment: my mistake RandomVariables is a header not a cpp.

As i mentioned I'm breaking down the tutorial code and building it into class systems as before it was all within a single file and everything global, i don't know enough DX to build it from scratch. but yes that would be the error given i only call camera.h in a second cpp when it opens up the error.

would you be able to provide an available solution? obviously removing all global variables is the current plan of action but i call MainCamera object in multiple files? potentially an extern will work?

Comment: If you stay with globals, then the definition in the header should be `extern`, and one and only one source (.CPP) module will have the "non-extern" definition.

Comment: ok thanks, thought that was a potential fix after you explained the flaw, will re-code it now to make sure.

much appreciated!

Comment: Just as a note, using ``XMVECTOR`` and ``XMMATRIX`` in a class only works easily with x64 native. The alignment requirements for these are not met by default on x86 or ARM. You might consider using [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using `externs` and just declaring the class object within the relative cpp files solved the issue.