# Global windows in SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am working on a little project in C++ with SDL2.  I am trying to create a global window which I can use in my other .cpp files, but I cant figure out how to make a global variable in SDL. And please don't write something like "Don't use global variables", because I have to use them, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Global variable in SDL works same like in C++, do you know how to use global variable in C++? If no, look on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702053/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-c

Comment: You can have an argument of `SDL_Window *&` in your different functions and pass it around.  Create the window in `main` send it to the application loop and close it when `main` exits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In every file you need it just declare it as `extern SDL_Window* GWindow;` and use it; then in single .cpp file define it `SDL_Window* GWindow = nullptr;`

Comment: Thanks dude! This just saved me many hours of looking for it.