# Symbol defined multiple times

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

How could I find out where I go wrong in the following situation?

In my project I have a header file named "appconstants.h".
It contains a global variable:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
extern int                      g_iSpeakerLCID = 1031;
```

I'm using this header file in one cpp file of the project. This works fine:

```
#include "appconstants.h"
```

Now when I declare the same header in another cpp file of the same project, I get the compiler error

```
"int g_iSpeakerLCID (?g_iSpeakerLCID@@3HA) is already defined in compiler.obj.
```

What's happening here or what should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not initialize in an `extern` declaration - initialize only at the definition point. Your `extern` declaration should be only:

```
extern int g_iSpeakerLCID;
```

Comment: I'm using this extern int througout my entire project, and it never changes and should be hardcoded. Whenever I want to change it, I change it only in this appconstants.h (and only at compilation). What would be the proper way to do what I want to do? I have multiple versions of my application, and each version has a different value. Before compilation, I write the appconstants.h anew using an external editor, using the desired value (like "1031").

Comment: I augmented your answer with this explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702053/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-c I mean the answer by @LuchianGrigore

Answer (score 0):

Despite the checkmark....

You can do it all in the header file. Replace `extern` with `inline`. Be sure the properties are set with C/C++ -> Language -> C++ Language Standard -> ISO C++17.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
inline int g_iSpeakerLCID = 1031;
```

It is a bad, *bad* idea to put `using namespace std;` in a header file (or anywhere in production code, usually.)

Also, it might be good to put `g_iSpeakerLCD` into a namespace rather than letting it flap around in the global namespace.